# struggling with PHP extensions

Tags: php, pecl

I have a PHP script that uses some simple extensions(curl, http_pecl, ...). I installed in my machine using macports and it worked fine. I tried to get this to run on another machine, but for some reason the set up is different, and the php extensions refuse to install. My question is, is it possible to bundle php extensions with the file itself so that it is standalone? im guessing to include the extensions with the file itself, but im not sure how to do that.

Both the machines are running Mac OSX Lion, so that takes away the OS constraint if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not possible. Whatever extensions your script requires must be manually installed by an administrator. An alternative such as you describe would have colossal reliability and security problems.

Comment: The one alternative that I found, though out of scope of this question, would be to get the same php setup on a virtual machine.